# Generate Thumbnail from base64_decode from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, base64, cakephp-2.0

Im trying to make code for generate thumbnail from base64_decode from mySQL Database but problem is why it said file is not valid JPEG im sure that source file is pure JPG file format. then I can't solve :(

source file (BASE64_ENCODE):
http://pastebin.com/wFBcd79B

image.php in view/Helper folder code:

```
<?php
class ImageHelper extends Helper {
    var $helpers = array('Html');
    var $cacheDir = 'imagecache';

    function getfile($i) {

        preg_match_all("/data:(.*);base64,/", $i, $temp_imagetype);

        $imagetype = $temp_imagetype[1][0];

        $image = base64_decode(preg_replace("/data.*base64,/","",$i));

        //echo $image;

        ob_start();

        //header("Content-type: ".$imagetype);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        print($image);

        $data = ob_get_clean();

        //file_put_contents($this->webroot.'tmp/temp.jpg', 'test' );

        file_put_contents(ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'tmp/temp.jpg', $data );


        //return ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'tmp/temp2.jpg';
        //return 'temp2.jpg';
        return 'temp.jpg';
    //}
    }


    //source from: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/hundleyj/2007/02/16/image-resize-helper and modified for base64_decode
    function resize($path, $width, $height, $aspect = true, $htmlAttributes = array(), $return = false) {
        $types = array(1 => "gif", "jpeg", "png", "swf", "psd", "wbmp"); // used to determine image type 

        //$fullpath = ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.$this->themeWeb.IMAGES_URL;

        $fullpath = ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.IMAGES_URL;

        $temppath = ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'tmp/';


        //$formImage = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode(preg_replace("/data.*base64,/","",$path)));

        //$url = $formImage;

        //$path = $this->getfile($path);

        $url = $temppath.$path;

        //$url = preg_replace("/data.*base64,/","",$path);

        //$url = base64_decode($url);

        if (!($size = getimagesize($url)))
            return; // image doesn't exist

        if ($aspect) { // adjust to aspect.
            if (($size[1]/$height) > ($size[0]/$width))  // $size[0]:width, [1]:height, [2]:type
                $width = ceil(($size[0]/$size[1]) * $height);
            else
                $height = ceil($width / ($size[0]/$size[1]));
        }

        $relfile = $this->cacheDir.'/'.$width.'x'.$height.'_'.basename($path); // relative file
        $cachefile = $fullpath.$this->cacheDir.DS.$width.'x'.$height.'_'.basename($path);  // location on server

        if (file_exists($cachefile)) {
        $csize = getimagesize($cachefile);
        $cached = ($csize[0] == $width && $csize[1] == $height); // image is cached
        if (@filemtime($cachefile) < @filemtime($url)) // check if up to date
            $cached = false;
        } else {
            $cached = false;
        }

        if (!$cached) {
            $resize = ($size[0] > $width || $size[1] > $height) || ($size[0] < $width || $size[1] < $height);
        } else {
            $resize = false;
        }

        if ($resize) {
            $image = call_user_func('imagecreatefrom'.$types[$size[2]], $url);
            if (function_exists("imagecreatetruecolor") && ($temp = imagecreatetruecolor ($width, $height))) {
                imagecopyresampled ($temp, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], $size[1]);
            } else {
                $temp = imagecreate ($width, $height);
                imagecopyresized ($temp, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], $size[1]);
            }
                call_user_func("image".$types[$size[2]], $temp, $cachefile);
                imagedestroy ($image);
                imagedestroy ($temp);
        }
        return $this->output(sprintf($this->Html->image($relfile,$htmlAttributes)));
    }
}
?>
```

'index.php' in view folder code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($products as $product):
        echo $this->Image->resize($this->Image->getfile($product['Product']['image1']), 120, 120, false); 
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

Output is error log:

```
> Warning (2): imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]:
> gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file 
> [APP/View/Helper/image.php, line 86] 
> Warning (2): imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]:
> '/Users/user/Sites/mycakeapp/app/webroot/tmp/temp.jpg' is not a valid
> JPEG file [APP/View/Helper/image.php, line 86] 
> Warning (2): imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given
> [APP/View/Helper/image.php, line 88] 
> Warning (2): imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
> [APP/View/Helper/image.php, line 94]
```

Comment: Have you looked into the output source? Maybe there are PHP error messages that break the JPG

Comment: yep output source i can view it after it saved temp.jpg... no corrupted file...

Comment: the whole idea is terribly wrong. Storing base64encoded data in a database is a nonsense. Storing images in the database is a huge performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

The base64 encoded data you link to is exactly 2¹⁶ (65536) bytes long. That number is just too round to be a coincidence.

Is the database column defined as `TEXT`? Convert it to something bigger, like `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT`.

It would make more sense to store images in the file system. While databases can store arbitrary data like files, there are limitations that make it impractical: A larger amount of data has to be transferred from the database server to the application over a network so there's a performance issue. Huge databases take longer to back up. And you may need to modify database settings:

> The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by its type, but the largest value you actually can transmit between the client and server is determined by the amount of available memory and the size of the communications buffers. You can change the message buffer size by changing the value of the `max_allowed_packet variable`, but you must do so for both the server and your client program.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: i decided not to use base64 encoded data coz it may damage file. do storing image in the database like regular data. and i did changed type LongText to LongBLOB...